# How to change default twig error templates in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am building an app using Symfony 4.4. I am trying to render custom 404 error page. I followed the documentation and created error.html.twig and error404.html.twig files in templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception. However I still get the 'Oops! An Error Occurred' with code 500 page that is by default from symfony.
Can someone point what can have I done wrong?
In dev mode I see that the app throws NotFoundHttpException but in prod mode I always get the page with code 500 even if I visit an undefined route.
This is what I get when I visit an undefiend route:
[500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viOQL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in Twig error renderer to override the default error templates. Both the TwigBundle and TwigBridge need to be installed for this
When the error page loads, Symfony\Bridge\Twig\ErrorRenderer\TwigErrorRenderer is used to render a Twig template to show the user.

This renderer uses the HTTP status code and the following logic to determine the template filename:

Look for a template for the given status code (like error500.html.twig);
If the previous template doesn’t exist, discard the status code and look for a generic error template (error.html.twig).
To override these templates, rely on the standard Symfony method for overriding templates that live inside a bundle and put them in the templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/ directory.

Comment: Yes I did rely on the standard Symfony method for overriding those templates but they still don't seem to load. Plus my error code is always 500